# Error with JsonSyntaxException when use Retrofit 2 get JSON

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I try to get JSON from server by Retrofit 2 but I got this error:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Mon Feb 29 08:12:40 GMT+00:00
>   2016

This is some line of code what I init the Gson and Retrofit :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
                .create();
        Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        RESTDatabaseDAO service = client.create(RESTDatabaseDAO.class);

        Call<Message> call = service.getLastMessage(objectItem.getUserId(), AppConfig.USER_ID);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Message>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Message> call, Response<Message> response) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    Message message = response.body();
                    Log.i("In retrofit method success message", response.body() + "");
                    viewHolder.tv_lastMessage.setText(message.getMessage());
                } else {
                    Log.i("In retrofit method failure", response.body() + "");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Message> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("In retrofit method failure message", t.toString());
            }


        });
```

This is my data in database:

> Mon Feb 29 08:12:40 GMT+00:00 2016

**UPDATE:**
This is my JSON String:

> {"messageId":1,"message":"new","expiresTime":"Fri Mar 04 02:12:39
>   GMT+00:00 2016","senderId":2,"userId":1}

Comment: I think the issue is with your json syntax . Please please validate your JSON

Comment: Yes but can I get that date data with this DateTime pattern: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` ?

Comment: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ