# JSON syntax for date time

Tags: json, retrofit

My server return this JSON String but seems like the syntax is not right. (I use Retrofit to get that json but it show `JsonSyntaxException` at `expiresTime` field. ). Could anyone check it for me:

```
{"messageId":1,"message":"new","expiresTime":"Fri Mar 04 02:12:39 GMT+00:00 2016","senderId":2,"userId":1}
```

This is image when I call that API by browser:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Please take a look at my old question: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767182/error-with-jsonsyntaxexception-when-use-retrofit-2-get-json)

Answer (score 1):

The entire string needs to be 1 line. You have 2 lines which is why its throwing the error for you. Output should be like:

```
{"messageId":1,"message":"new","expiresTime":"Fri Mar 04 02:12:39 GMT+00:00 2016","senderId":2,"userId":1}
```

Similar questions:

- [Multiline strings in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json)
- [Can a JSON value contain a multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690101/can-a-json-value-contain-a-multiline-string)

Comment: It just return in one line. Could you take a look in my question, I've just update it :) I become 2 lines when I wrote the question :D

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy Can you post what you get when you view the page source? Is it the same as what you see in the browser?

Comment: I don't understand this part : "when you view the page source", which is page sources?

Comment: I've just update my question above. Please take a look on it.